# HikariCP Stuck in idle connections

Tags: hibernate, jboss-arquillian, hikaricp

I have a problem executing an application using HikariCP with hibernate 5.1.0.Final. The connections seems to be stuck at some point in an idle state, as you can see in the following log entry:

2017-08-04 11:13:28 [TreasyPool housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - TreasyPool - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)

Any idea concerning what are the conditions required to keep a connection in HikariCP on an idle state? It happens during the execution of integration test with arquillian. The persistence.xml, which contains the HikariCP configuration parameters, is the following:

```
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Alterado para compatibilidade do hibernate5 -->
    <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>

    <!-- Garante que o Envers persista as informaçõesda entidade quando apagado-->
    <property name="org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete">true</property>

    <!-- Connection Pool with HikariCP -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">virtual#_root$</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.101:2387/prod_test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">10</property>        
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.isolateInternalQueries">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold">290000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">10000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime">300000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.autoCommit">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.poolName">TestPool</property>


    <!-- Second-Level Cache -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>

</session-factory>
```

Kind regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"?  Idle is the normal state for connections in the pool when not in use.

Comment: I have neither a deadlock nor a starvation condition in the source code, and it is why I have asked about  what are the conditions required to keep a connection in HikariCP on an idle state, as the integration tests I am running do not finish.

Comment: Are you sure you are shutting down the pool properly?  This is the most common issue I see with unit tests and integration tests.  I recommend turning on debug logging.